# "The handle is invalid" error when writing to eventlog using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, event-log

I am working with an ASP.NET 2.0 application (created by my predecessor). Users log into it with AD credentials, and everything done within the app uses those credentials. I modified a page in the application that has nothing to do with event logging, and now my users get this error:
[image: Handle is invalid error]

Here is the relevant code from the global.asax file:

```
public void LogException(Exception e)
    {
        string exceptionXml = RenderException(e, true);

        _EventLog.WriteEntry("Exception of type " + e.GetType().FullName + " occurred.\n\n" + exceptionXml, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
```

RenderException() just puts the exception XML into a flat string, removing white spaces.

I am at a loss on how to get rid of this error. I have tried re-publishing the website with an iisreset. I have tried restarting the web server (2k3 w/ iis 6.0), flushing the app pool. I have also tried modifying the permissions in the registry for the top-level event log key. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error? It does not happen on my computer, so it is very hard to replicate. Also, the browser used does not seem to matter. The previous version will work for the same persons getting this error.

Comment: Just FYI "Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege." via http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that! I'll edit the disclaimer out.

Answer (score 0):

By default the **ASPNET** user cannot access the existing event logs categories.

If you do want to write messages to the event log you must create your own category

1. Launch RegEdit
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\
   CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\
3. From the menu, select Edit->Permissions
4. Click the Add button and write ASPNET.  (if ASP.NET is running under a different user id, use that id instead)
5. Click OK.
6. Select the newly added user from the list (ASP.NET Machine User by default).
7. Click on Full Control in the Allow column.
8. Click OK.

You can also check that the user, under which the applications is running, belongs to the correct group, for example **IIS_WPG**

**http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3648346f-e4f5-474b-86c7-5a86e85fa1ff.mspx?mfr=true**

Comment: I may not have made it clear enough, but I have already tried this ("I have also tried modifying the permissions in the registry for the top-level event log key."). I made sure all users in the intranet group (they need this to access the site) have full control on the top level Event Log key. Unless I'm missing something (like a restart after) that did not work...

Comment: @HeyThereLameMan I just added more info that might help you

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be calling an instance method of the EventLog class on the `_EventLog` instance:

```
_EvengLog.WriteEvent(message, ...);
```

But [according to MSDN documentation for the EventLog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx):

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

I suspect this is a likely source of your problem, and would recommend you use one of the static methods (which are guaranteed to be thread safe):

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEvent(source, message, ...);
```

Alternatively you could implement your own synchronization, but I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: I was able to get this in place and on my production server. My users still get this error, but I do not. It is very sporadic. It also has the same stack trace, so I don't think the issue is solved. Is there some kind of refresh I need to do on the user machine to get it to work?

Comment: @HeyThereLameMan - I still think that this error is most likely due to a threading issue.  You should check the whole code base for such threading issues.